# After installing kong by luarocks, how do I install the binary and run it?

Tags: kong, luarocks

I installed kong by luarocks with this command:

```
luarocks install kong 0.14.1-0
```

[image]

but i can't find the binary 'kong' to start service. The document (like below), Where is the `bin`?:

[image]

Comment: I took a little license here, but it sounds like the asker is really talking about figuring out how to run a program that the asker has installed from source.

Comment: If you are trying to install from source there's different documentation for that [here](https://docs.konghq.com/install/source/) and if you have further questions about Kong feel free to ask in our [forum](https://discuss.konghq.com/) where they might get more views from our engineers.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I ran into this as well.

I had a 'duh' moment once I figured this out, so you might too. :)

Turns out the `bin/kong` file is a simple script file that's in the github source. So, just copy it from https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/bin/kong and place it in your path, i.e.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kong/master/bin/kong
chmod a+x kong
sudo mv kong /usr/local/bin/
```

Would be nice if the `luarocks install kong 1.1.2-0` command fetches that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. Basically I could not find the dir from which the KONG source code was cloned from git. Perhaps, that dir contains KONG bin inside. However, you can try to clone the source code by your self and try to compile by using the command:

> make install

OR

> luarocks make

After the compilation you can check the `bin` dir inside the source code dir that you have cloned from git.

Ref:

- https://docs.konghq.com/install/source
- https://github.com/Kong/kong

Comment: You can checkout the version you want to compile and install. In this case just cd to the dir that you have cloned the source code and run: `git checkout tags/<version>` to switch to the release branch of the target version.