# Not found kong command after install kong by ruarocks

Tags: kong

In Ubuntu 16.04 VM, I installed `kong` following in the official instruction at https://docs.konghq.com/install/source/.

Use Luarocks to install Kong’s Lua sources:

```
 $ luarocks install kong 2.0.4-0
```

After executed this command, I got a message in the console output:

```
kong 2.0.4-0 is now installed in /usr/local (license: Apache 2.0).
```

When running `kong` command, no `kong` command found.

The alternative is to use git:

```
  $ git clone git@github.com:Kong/kong.git
  $ cd kong
  $ [sudo] make install # this simply runs the `luarocks make kong-*.rockspec` command
```

Docs say "Finally, place the bin/kong script in your $PATH."

With the first means(luarocks), I can't find a path containing "bin/kong".
With the second means(git), I can find "bin/kong" in the source code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047067/4983501 this answer suggested to use the kong script from the source code.

So I have to do this by myself with the means of luarocks?
Is it an issue about luarocks installing kong in Ubuntu?

Comment: is there a bin/kong in the directory /usr/local/kong ?

Comment: No, there isn't. That's the problem. Only installing with PACKAGES can find file /usr/local/bin/kong there.